# Webpack Checking started in seperate process - missing

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, webpack-2

When building my Angular2 + Typescript code using Webpack my bundling used to say at the very end:

```
webpack: bundle is now VALID
[default] Checking started in sepearte process
[default] Ok, 3.72 sec.
```

I screwed something up.  Now it stops at `webpack: bundle is now VALID` and doesn't show the other two comments.  Furthermore, if there are previous errors that occurred they aren't shown in a summary at the very end like they used to and I have to scroll back up to find them.

- Angular 2.4.1
- typescript 2.0.10
- webpack 2.1.0-beta.25
- webpack-dev-middleware 1.8.1
- webpack-dev-server 2.1.0-beta.4
- webpack-merge 0.14.1
- Project cloned from: [Qdouble Starter](https://github.com/qdouble/angular-webpack2-starter.git)

Comment: FYI–Webpack 2.2 now offers a different output as well as an optional performance flag.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.  I guess I should wait longer before posting a question.  I ended up upgrading all webpack and typescript related libraries and my config files to the same version and format that is in Qdouble's starter (shown above) and everything is working fine now.  While it still doesn't show the last two `[default]` lines, I do show current errors when they exist without having to constantly scroll up.